# Smack in Android Studio really puzzle me

Tags: android, android-studio, smack

I use Eclipse before changing to AS,but something really puzzle me.
I import the Smack4.1.4 into app/libs,and set the dependencies.
Everything looks OK without one exception.
 Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext"

I have searched about it, it seems that `javax.naming` is not in android's whitelist.

So how could i use smack in AS? That's a big problem for me.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to stop importing jar files and start using gradle to resolve the dependencies, that's a major difference in how you import libraries in Android Studio vs Eclipse, only import jars if they are not available from a repository:

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

Example:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
  }
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0"
  compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I solve this problem.

Actually, I also need to import the following jar:

1. `dnsjava:dnsjava`
2. `org.jxmpp:jxmpp-core`
3. `org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid`
4. `org.jxmpp:jxmpp-util-cache`

Hope my answer will help some beginners like me.  :)

Answer (score -1):

After 1 day i finally resolve this issue in nativescript android.
Dont add dnsjava.(version).jar , smack-java7-version.jar
Add smack-resolver-dnsjava-4.2.1.jar